# Erlang - fwrite tilde

Tags: erlang

If a string contains a `~`, I can't seem to print that to standard out.

```
> A = "/.git".
> io:fwrite(A).
/.gitok

> B = "~/.git".
> io:fwrite(B).
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  io:format/3
    called as io:format(<0.50.0>,"~/.git",[])
```

How can I print a string with tildes to standard out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `io:fwrite/1,2,3` and `io:format/1,2,3` when you don't need formatting. Those functions are intended where you would need `printf()` or `fprintf()` in C. If you want just output already prepared iodata use `io:put_chars/1,2`.

Answer (score 5):

> If a string contains a `~`, I can't seem to print that to standard out.

To format output, you construct a string containing *format sequences* that start with a `~`. Erlang thinks your string contains a *format sequence*.  If you want Erlang to output a literal `~`, you can escape it with another `~`:

```
22> io:format("~~/.git~n").
~/.git
ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print a string with tildes to standard out using the control sequences ~p

```
 ~ → erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1>  B = "~/.git".
"~/.git"
2> io:fwrite("~p",[B]).
"~/.git"ok
3> io:fwrite("~p~n",[B]).
"~/.git"
ok
4>
```